# Eclipse Debug mode & Exceptions

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, exception

I'm sure this has been asked before, but I looked and don't see a definitive answer anywhere.

In eclipse, while debugging Android program, if I cause an exception Eclipse always wants to pull up the source file where the actual throw statement is contained. I don't have the source attached (nor do I want to), so it brings up this 'Source not found' window for android.jar every time I hit an exception.

I know I can look at the logcat to see the call stack, but is there any way to make eclipse automatically open the file that I caused the exception from (the deepest file in the call stack for which source exists), and not the android.jar? It seems like a trivial thing to do, but instead I'm always stuck looking at this useless page every time, when I think a smart solution would be to automatically pull up the file from my source code that caused the problem. Instead I have to look at the call stack, return back to 'java' view, and find the offending file myself and open it, which is pretty onerous.

Is there any way to improve my IDE setup so I get more useful information right away than looking at this useless class not found page?

Comment: interesting question, I don't know if it possible, but if it's good enough for you and you didn't think about it before - you can add to your code a try/catch(Exception e) block where you know the exception occurs, and look on the message...      I guess you know that, but that what I have to say :)

Answer (score 1):

Try using [step filters](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t83338.rhtml) (Editable in properties: Window - Preferences - Java - Debug - Step Filters). 
That way you can ignore certain packages where you do not have the sources available.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have tried it, but it doesn't seem to filter exceptions. Seems to only effect manually stepping through in code.